# Getting a subcolletion that has fields with references to other collections and their document data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called Users. Inside of that collection each user is added with his own ID etc. Inside of a Users Doc you have a sub collection called **skin_collection** and inside of that fields that are of type Reference which points to another collection and a document inside of that.

So as an example (sorry for formatting):

Users

- Document: 123

  - skin_collection

    - Document: 1

      - Field 1: 'knives/1WnPRlqLPe8Y12YXtm8T'

I'd like to get that referenced docs data so I can use it on the page. Currently I have this useEffect running on the page:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const getData = async () => {
        const userRef = doc(db, "Users", user.uid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
          console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
          setUserData(docSnap.data());

          const parentDocRef = doc(db, "Users", user.uid);

          const skinCollectionRef = collection(parentDocRef, "skin_collection");
          skinCollectionRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
              const docData = doc.data();
              Object.keys(docData).forEach(async (key) => {
                if (docData[key] && docData[key].isEqual) {
                  console.log(`${key} is a reference field`);
                  const referencedDocSnapshot = await docData[key].get();
                  if (referencedDocSnapshot.exists) {
                    console.log(`${key} data:`, referencedDocSnapshot.data());
                  } else {
                    console.log(`${key} does not exist`);
                  }
                }
              });
            });
          });
        } else {
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      };
      getData();
    }
  }, [user]);
```

It uses the current logged in user ID to reference its document. I want to get all the data from the subcollection and then those referenced documents's data but it seems Im struggling to get that going.

Comment: a tip for writing document databases, make the data as flat as possible

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear about what specifically you're struggling with.  What you have now makes it hard to tell what the problem is.